# Node.JS and PHP AES-128-EBC data encryption

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm trying to generate an encrypted block of data in javascript (node.js), and then pass to another system via HTTP. I've been given a reference system in php to compare my results with.

For reasons that are seemingly beyond my grasp I cannot get my javascript version to produce the same encrypted data as the PHP version. I've checked that the keys I'm using are the same. Does anyone have any clues or tips what so ever on what I'm doing wrong.

(Yes I know the ECB is bad, but it's not my choice)

#### Reference PHP implementation

```
<?php

function getEncrypt($str, $key)
{
    $realKey = substr($key, 0, 16);
    $padding = pkcs5_pad($str, 16);
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $realKey, $padding, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}


$key = "oi3sgkosQPIdFa0eVSjecIhkha2nAfpn3anAozln0e9rkIGPvzUBgToCtlXLsKyjBITGKozHmn1NArgQodawidiVnyxccsf8ZnUgof4kq0iBCS7wrG1raytauMusRjjb";
$string = '{"pol.start":"11-06-2012 09:00:00","pol.end.after":43200,"lic.cache":"yes","playback":2880,"out.digital":"use","out.analog":"use"}';

$encData = getEncrypt($string, $key);

var_dump($encData);
```

#### My Javascript attempt:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cipherAlgo = 'AES-128-ECB';

var policy = '{"pol.start":"11-06-2012 09:00:00","pol.end.after":43200,"lic.cache":"yes","playback":2880,"out.digital":"use","out.analog":"use"}';
var sharedSecret = 'oi3sgkosQPIdFa0eVSjecIhkha2nAfpn3anAozln0e9rkIGPvzUBgToCtlXLsKyjBITGKozHmn1NArgQodawidiVnyxccsf8ZnUgof4kq0iBCS7wrG1raytauMusRjjb';


var util = require('util');


function encrypt(string, key)
{
    var realKey = key.substring(0,16);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(cipherAlgo, key.substring(0,16));
    //encrypt our string
    var encrypted = cipher.update(string, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
}


console.log(encrypt(policy, sharedSecret));
```

I have tried lots of things like rejigging output to binary, putting into a buffer and base64ing that etc etc.
For the love of my sanity can someone help on this.

Comment: Have you seen [the ECB penguin](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin)?